# Running a Timer From Within a Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, counter

I would link to execute a method from within my thread every 5 seconds. The outline of my class is as follows.

```
private static Timer timer = new Timer();

public class myThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        //listens for incoming messages
        while(true) {

            //process queue
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            process_queue();
            }, 5*1000);
        }
    }  

    public static void process_queue() {
        //processes queue
        System.out.println("boom");

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I need to be able to constantly listen for incoming messages, but process queue from db every 5 seconds. I am having problems running the timer within the while loop.

Comment: Schedule the task once, with repetition. The thread you call `schedule` on is irrelevant, `Timer` maintains its own thread for scheduled tasks.

Comment: I guess I could schedule the task once after completion if no alternative was possible.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with your code here:

```
//listens for incoming messages
while(true) {

    //process queue
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    process_queue();
    }, 5*1000);
}
```

is that it is going to schedule unlimited tasks - this is infinite loop that is spawning tasks which all are going to be run after 5 seconds.

Try something like this:

```
public void run() {

        //listens for incoming messages
        while(true) {
            process_queue();
            sleep(5000); //watch out for Exception handling (i.e. InterruptedException)
        }
    }
```

Although in todays software development trends you would like to avoid `blocking` waiting (i.e. sleep() methods blocks current thread). See Akka Actors - http://akka.io/

Also you are saying that you want to run a method every 5 seconds, but `need to be able to constantly listen for incoming messages`. Could you clarify? Cheers